# When does open descending sequence contain closed descending sequence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> In a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$, consider any descending sequence of nonempty open sets: $A_{1} \supset A_{2} \supset A_{3} \supset \dots$, when does there exist a a descending sequence of nonempty closed sets $C_{1} \supset C_{2} \supset C_{3} \supset\dots$ such that for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$, $C_{i} \subset A_{i}$?

I think this is false in general, for instance, consider the topology $(X, \{ A,\emptyset,X\})$, where $\emptyset \neq A \subset X$. $A$ itself forms a descending chain. I tried to see if using $T_{3}$ would help, or if this is true for general metric spaces, but is a little stuck. However, I felt this question should be simple.

I was thinking about some basic theorems such as characterization of completeness and compactness, and Baire Category theorem, which led me to wonder about this.

Comment: Just to be sure, your $\supset$'s mean $\supseteq$ here, right? (Otherwise your example doesn't make sense)

Comment: @BenSteffan Yeah, I think both are used in literature or $\supsetneq$ is used for the strict case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $X$ is T1, then it is sufficient to assume that $\bigcap_i A_i \neq \emptyset$ since $C_i = x$ for all $i$ where $x \in \bigcap_i A_i$ is any point does the job, seeing as points in T1-spaces are closed. If $X$ isn't T1, you can of course replace the assumption by "$\bigcap_i A_i$ contains a closed set," but I'm not sure that you can do any better.

In the case $\bigcap_i A_i = \emptyset$, I don't think one can say much: Even if you assume that $X$ is a metric space, it can both happen that a sequence $C_i$ exists and that it doesn't. For the first case, consider for instance $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete metric and let $A_i = \{i, i + 1, \ldots \}$. Clearly $\bigcap_i A_i = \emptyset$, but since $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete you can of course just let $C_i = A_i$ and be done. On the other hand, if you consider $\mathbb{R}$ and $A_i = (0, 1 / i)$, then no sequence $\{C_i\}_i$ exists, for we would have $C_1 \cap (0, 1 / i) \neq \emptyset$ for all $i$, which implies that $0 \notin C_1$ is a limit point, but that is absurd as $C_1$ is closed.